# Proving a result from the Fourier Energy Theorem

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

So I don't know what the result is called as it is unstated in the problem but it is a proof following from the Fourier Energy theorem.
Prove:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'(x)f'^*(x)dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\omega^2\hat{f}(\omega)\hat{f}^*(\omega)d\omega$$

using:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f(x))^2dx  = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\|\hat{f}(\omega)\|^2 $$

What I have done so far is replace $\|\hat{f}(\omega)\|^2 $ with $ \hat{f}(\omega)\hat{f}^*(\omega)$
to get

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)f(x)dx  = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{f}(\omega)\hat{f}^*(\omega) $$

now my idea was to use the Fourier transform property:
$\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{d^nf}{dx^n}\right)  = (i\omega)^n\hat{f}(\omega)$
but was confused as to how this would work, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you nearly got it. If you use in your formula $f'$ instead of $f$ you can use $\mathcal F(f')(\omega)=i\omega f(\omega)$.

So we are using the Parval identiy on $f'$ to get:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)f'^{*}(x)dx=\tfrac 1 {2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\widehat{ f'}(\omega)\widehat {f'}^*(\omega)d\omega$$
Now we can use the Fourier poperty and get with $\widehat{f'}(\omega)=i\omega\hat f(\omega)$:
$$\tfrac 1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\underbrace{(i\omega)\hat f(\omega)}_{=\widehat{f'}(\omega)}\underbrace{(i\omega)^*\hat f^*(\omega)}_{=\widehat{f'}^*(\omega)}d\omega=\tfrac 1 {2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\underbrace{-i^2}_{=1}\omega^2\hat f(\omega)\hat f^*(\omega)d\omega$$

Comment: @Salafur thanks for your answer, I had two follow-ups about your answer if you don't mind. In your first equation, you have $ \int f'(x)f'^*(x)dx $ according to the energy theorem it seems you have replaced f'(x) with its conjugate. Under what conditions is this allowed? And lastly, where you have used the Fourier property, does this mean $ \hat{f}'(\omega) $ is equivalent to $ \mathcal{F}\frac{d^nf}{dx^n} $

Comment: At first let $\mathcal L^1:=\left\{g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C \quad measuarble| \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)| dx <\infty\right \}$.

For the first equation I use the Parsval Identity for the Fourier transform $\mathcal F:\mathcal L^1 \to \mathcal C_0$. That means  if $g,\hat g,h,\hat h\in \mathcal L^1$ then we know that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)h^*(x)dx=\tfrac 1 {2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat g(\omega)\hat h *(\omega)d\omega$.

So we need here in our case $f,f',\hat f, \widehat{f'}\in \mathcal L^1$. And yes, by $\widehat {f'} $ i mean $\mathcal F (\tfrac {d}{dx})$

Comment: What information are exactly given for your function $f$ ? Where does it come from ($\mathcal L^1,\mathcal L^2$)? And is your function real valued?  Because then is $|f(x)|^2=(f(x))^2$. And I think we need that $f,f',\hat f,\widehat{f'} \in \mathcal L^2$ too, but I am not sure about hat. I will look tomorrow again.